# Suppose $\mu$ is a finite measure, show that $\phi_\mu(t):\int_R e^{itx}d \mu (x)$ is continous.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\mu$ is a finite measure on $\mathbb{B}(R)$, show that $\phi_\mu(t):\int_R e^{itx}d \mu (x)$ is continous.

---

in the lecture we had the following theorem:

Let $(S,A,\mu)$ be a measure space. $u_0 \in U \subseteq R^d$, $f:U\times S \to R $ with

(i) $\mu -  a.e.: \forall x \in S: u\to f(u,x)$ continous in $u_0$

(ii) $\forall u \in U: x\to f(u,x) $ measurable

(iii) $\exists g \ge 0$, g $\mu$-integrable $\forall u \in U, \forall x \in S: |f(u,x)|\le g(x)$

### Then the function $F: U \to R : u \mapsto \int f(u,x)d\mu(x)$ is continous

So now i want to use this theorem to argue that my function $\phi_\mu $ is continous:

(i) $e^{itx}$ is continous $\forall t \in R$

(ii) $e^{itx}$ is measurable... ( is it really? )

(iii) Here i have to find such a integrable majorant function g.

If i could make (ii) and (iii) work i would have the Continuity of $\phi_mu$

Comment: ii) Continuity implies measurability. iii) Take $g(x)=1$ for all $x$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Your statement about measurabikity only holds true if we consider the Borel sigma algebra. Though I suspect that the OP is just missing to state this assumption.

Comment: Dave, is your finite measure supposed to be a Borel measure? Otherwise your integrand might fail to be measurable. Consider the trivial sigma algebra $\{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}$, then $x\mapsto e^{ixt}$ is not measurable for $t\neq 0$.

Comment: ohh, my bad  ... yes the sigma algebra is $B(R)$ 
I will edit it

Comment: Dave, if you want to reply to somebody, you need to tag them as I did in my first comment. Otherwise the other user will not be notified and your message might not be seen.